# ERROR ITMS-90034 Apple store submitting phonegap error

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, phonegap-build, appstore-approval

So when trying to upload my app to the app store im getting this error:

ERROR ITMS-90034 - Missing or invalid signature. [App path] is not signed using an Apple submission certificate.

Ive tried remaking my certificates and the project builds perfectly on phonegap build.

After I download the ipa file im importing it into Application Loader 3.0 and when importing the app It throws that error.

Not sure why its erroring as the certificates associated with the app are all production certificates and profiles.

Im not using xcode so is there something i have to do with cordova to prepare it for production?

Ive compiled it for ios so i know theres an ios version.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a week long discussion with Phonegap and Apple the issue has finally been figured out.

Found here:
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/error-itms-90034-missing-or-invalid-signature

So I finally found out the issue.. The issue wasn't with the certificates, after i built the project in cordova for ios I opened the xcode project. Trying to submit the app through xcode also didnt work. So through xcode I validated the project and compiled the api file through xcode instead of phonegap and from there used application loader to import to the appstore. This solved the issue. Maybe this is something phonegap need to look into since i shouldnt have to use xcode to compile my api file..

Also another thing i found was that itunes connect would be funny with app ids i created if i was using chrome. Had no issue when it came to safari.

So summarising, use safari when dealing with apple services (Annoying becasuse you do expect to use them anywhere) and I built the project in ios (cordova build ios - command), opened the xcode project it generates, then create the ipa file through xcode:

Step by step shown here: [How to use the C socket API in C++ on z/OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25)...

Before making the ipa file make sure you validate your app through xcode - this is very important.

Then using the ipa file it generates, use that in the application loader.

Im glad the issue has been solved but phonegap build needs to be looked at, i know it wasnt any other issue as xcode compiling the api file is the only difference in the process that works.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6):

Make change in Keychain Access for related Certification Authority certificate from "Always Trust" to "Use the system default".

This do the trick for me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using Intel XDK and trying to submit to Apple.  I got rid of (revoked) all other iOS certificate tries in my Apple dev account and started fresh and it worked. I think I had an ad hoc certificate in there and I wanted production, but I'm not sure if that was the actual problem.

Comment: Suppose it doesnt hurt to give that a try but cant do that every time i want to upload a different app to the app store, hopefully theres another solution. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this out too: http://blog.frumar.com/?p=18

I was getting hit with a totally obscure certificate trust issue. Turns out that if you change the trust settings on the "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority” certificate then all hell breaks loose.

Answer (score 0):

simply , i restared xcode , and it solved this issue for me.